# ValueError: features should be a dictionary of `Tensor`s. Given type: <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, linear-regression

I had made this Linear Regression Model using TensorFlow and am having this error==>

> ValueError: features should be a dictionary of 'Tensor's.
>   Basically, The model accepts a dataset in CSV format and takes the data out from the file

The whole TraceBack goes as follows:-

```
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-138-facba27f689a> in <module>
----> 1 model.train(steps = 1000, input_fn= lambda : input_fn(df_train, batch_size = 128, num_epoch = None))

c:\users\neelg\tf2_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
    368 
    369       saving_listeners = _check_listeners_type(saving_listeners)
--> 370       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    371       logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
    372       return self

c:\users\neelg\tf2_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1158       return self._train_model_distributed(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1159     else:
-> 1160       return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1161 
   1162   def _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners):

c:\users\neelg\tf2_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py in _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1188       worker_hooks.extend(input_hooks)
   1189       estimator_spec = self._call_model_fn(
-> 1190           features, labels, ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
   1191       global_step_tensor = training_util.get_global_step(g)
   1192       return self._train_with_estimator_spec(estimator_spec, worker_hooks,

c:\users\neelg\tf2_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py in _call_model_fn(self, features, labels, mode, config)
   1146 
   1147     logging.info('Calling model_fn.')
-> 1148     model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
   1149     logging.info('Done calling model_fn.')
   1150 

c:\users\neelg\tf2_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\linear.py in _model_fn(features, labels, mode, config)
   1345           optimizer=optimizer,
   1346           config=config,
-> 1347           sparse_combiner=sparse_combiner)
   1348 
   1349     super(LinearRegressorV2, self).__init__(

c:\users\neelg\tf2_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\linear.py in _linear_model_fn_v2(features, labels, mode, head, feature_columns, optimizer, config, sparse_combiner)
    659   if not isinstance(features, dict):
    660     raise ValueError('features should be a dictionary of `Tensor`s. '
--> 661                      'Given type: {}'.format(type(features)))
    662 
    663   del config

ValueError: features should be a dictionary of `Tensor`s. Given type: <class 'NoneType'>
```

**And Here is my code:---**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_train = "C:/Users/neelg/Documents/Jupyter/Linear-reg/boston_train.csv"
df_eval = "C:/Users/neelg/Documents/Jupyter/Linear-reg/boston_test.csv"

COLUMNS = ["crim", "zn", "indus", "nox", "rm", "age","dis", "tax", "ptratio", "medv"]
RECORDS_ALL = [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0],[0.0],[0.0],[0.0],[0.0],[0.0],[0.0]]

def input_fn(data_file, batch_size, num_epoch):
    def parse_csv(value):
        columns = tf.io.decode_csv(value, record_defaults= RECORDS_ALL)
        features = dict(zip(COLUMNS, columns))
        #labels = features.pop('median_house_value')
        labels =  features.pop('medv')
        return features, labels

          # Extract lines from input files using the dataset API
        dataset = (tf.data.TextLineDataset(data_file) # Read text file
        .skip(1) # Skip header row
        .map(parse_csv))

        dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epoch)
        dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
          # Here goes the iterator==>
        iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
        features, labels = iterator.get_next()
        return features, labels

X1= tf.feature_column.numeric_column('crim')
X2= tf.feature_column.numeric_column('zn')
X3= tf.feature_column.numeric_column('indus')
X4= tf.feature_column.numeric_column('nox')
X5= tf.feature_column.numeric_column('rm')
X6= tf.feature_column.numeric_column('age')
X7= tf.feature_column.numeric_column('dis')
X8= tf.feature_column.numeric_column('tax')
X9= tf.feature_column.numeric_column('ptratio')

base_columns = [X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9]

model = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=[base_columns], model_dir='train3')
#Training the estimator:
model.train(steps = 1000, input_fn= lambda : input_fn(df_train, batch_size = 128, num_epoch = None))
```

*BTW, x1,x2... refers to the columns of the dataset*

> This is how my training dataset looks like(The weird words represent the column headings)====>

```
400,9,CRIM,ZN,INDUS,NOX,RM,AGE,DIS,TAX,PTRATIO,MEDV
2.3004,0.0,19.58,0.605,6.319,96.1,2.1,403,14.7,23.8
13.3598,0.0,18.1,0.693,5.887,94.7,1.7821,666,20.2,12.7
```

As I was pretty sure the problem was in the "Input_fn" function,I converted from this

```
features = dict(tf.convert_to_tensor(zip(COLUMNS, columns)))
```

to this:-

```
features = dict(tf.convert_to_tensor(zip(COLUMNS, columns)))
```

But that didn't work either :( Any help??

**UPDATE**
Tried changing the line to this:

```
dataset = (tf.data.TextLineDataset(data_file).skip(1).map(parse_csv))
```

The function works properly now but the error remains...

Answer (score 0):

The `input_fn` function is not doing anything except defining a local function.
Once the `input_fn` function is called it simply returns the `None` object.

Comment: I instructed the input_fn to include the parse_csv(Basically whenever I call input_fn, parse_csv will be used) Yet the same error is received again. Any suggestions?

Comment: Because you have changed the behavior of the function, but you are still not returning anything... which causes the None object to be returned. You are using the function to generate a side effect, which works, but it still returns None until you explicitly return something else.